# elasticsearch: how to remove unassigned shards

Tags: elasticsearch

elasticsearch 1.7.x on centOS

Our three node cluster became a 2 node cluster.
All is well. We had 3 replicas of every shard, so we have it all.

But now cluster health is yellow, and we have:

```
 "unassigned_shards" : 5,
```

We already changed the replica count setting in elasticsearch.yml down to 1 (from 2) and restarted ES on both nodes. This made no difference.

What is the next step?

I see how to reassign shards, but not how to eliminate the unassigned shards.

Comment: It doesn't look like you last sentence is complete.

Comment: @Val incomplete sentence fixed. thx for heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the number_of_replicas in `elasticsearch.yaml` is not enough, this setting is only used when creating new indices.

Use the [Index Settings API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_settings.html) to change  the number of replicas of existing indexes:

```
PUT /_all/_settings
{
    "number_of_replicas": 2
}
```

Comment: OK.... but when I look at /_cat/shards, it still shows the UNASSIGNED replicas...  now what?

Comment: Ignore comment above. That is the ticket! Note, on a two-node cluster, set it to 1